# ASP.NET MVC Authorized Roles, with HasAccesss from the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, roles

We're using the `[Authorize (Roles="yadda, yadda2")]` attribute on our controllers and I'm wondering if there is a built in mechanism for discovering if they have access then from the view?

```
[Authorize (Roles="System Administrator, Administrator")]
public abstract class OperationsBaseContoller : BaseController
{
    // omitted
}

// some view
@if(HasAccessTo<OperationsBaseController>())
{
   <a href="#somewhereInOperations">Operations Action</a>
   <a href="#anotherInOps">Example</a>
   <a href="#oneMore">filler</a>
}
```

Something like above would be great so that I can avoid rendering links that can't be delivered to them anyways.  I do **NOT**, however, want to put list available roles in the view again has in `User.IsInRole("....")`, as this seems like a maintenance / duplicate code nightmare.   I figured that if they gave us the attribute, they also gave a built-in way for checking it from the view.

If not (couldn't find it on my own), I'll write my own, but wanted to avoid potential wheel reinvention.

Comment: You may be able to leverage the User.IsInRole("Admin") method on the IPrinciple for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few useful extension methods that accomplish exactly this

```
Html.ActionAuthorized

Html.ActionLinkAuthorized
```

published at

http://vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/create-an-authorized-action-link-extension-for-aspnet-mvc-3

> In this article I will explain how to create an action link extension that is authorizations aware, so that we can hide or disable an action link based on its authorizations.